# MySQL Select WHERE and LEFT JOIN with WHERE GROUP RESULT

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select from Table `A.Prod_Name where status is ACTIVE`, then count total of register from Table `B WHERE Table B.Status is OPENED` and if there's nothing on Table B, `Product_Name` count will be 0.

If there's a register on Table B to be counted, because it should look for registers with status OPENED, it shows the product name and count number, but if there's nothing for the product on Table B with status OPENED then it doesn't select the `Product_Name` on Table A that doesn't have any to be counted.

The `WHERE Table B.Status = 'OPENED'` condition has to affect only table B. not the table A, basically 2 where conditions, one at the product selection and another on left join selection but result count would be group by product.

```
SELECT
    tableA.prodID,
    tableA.prodName,
    COUNT(tableB.DetailsID) as numberDetails
FROM
    tableA
    LEFT JOIN tableB
        ON tableA.prodID = tableB.prodID
WHERE
    tableA.status = 'ACTIVE'
    and tableB.status = 'OPENED'
GROUP BY
    tableA.prodID
```

Comment: You need to work on explaining what you want more clearly.  Try providing sample data and desired results.  A query that you have already tried would also help.

Comment: Gordon, let me try to explain better. on table A.(Products) I want to select only the ones with status 'ACTIVE'. then I would like to count registers on table B.(details) for each product. but the thing is on table B(details) each register has a status also, (OPENED or CLOSED), so I want to count table B(Details) whatever have status OPENED for each product that was selected with status 'ACTIVE'. but if a product was ACTIVE but didn't have any DETAIL OPENED the count will return 0.

Comment: ok, I edited my question and posted the query. So what is happen is if a product is ACTIVE, but there's no DETAIL Regiters on table.B with status OPENED, then the product is not showing on my result with count 0, only the one's that has details registers to be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want to move the check for `OPENED` into the JOIN, so that tableA records that don't have status `OPENED` in tableB still show up.

```
SELECT
    tableA.prodID,
    tableA.prodName,
    COUNT(tableB.DetailsID) as numberDetails
FROM
    tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.prodID = tableB.prodID
    AND tableB.status = 'OPENED'
WHERE
    tableA.status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY
tableA.prodID
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was expecting the query to do. Thank you for the correction, it's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    tableA.prodId
    , tableA.prodname
    , cntQry.numberDetails 
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT 
      tableB.ProdId
      , COUNT(*) as numberDetails
  FROM tableB 
  WHERE tableB.status = 'OPENED'
  GROUP BY tableB.ProdId) cntQry
ON tableA.ProdId = cntQry.ProdId
WHERE tableA.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: Note that this won't return a "zero" value for a count for any ProdID that doesn't appear in tableB. It would be possible to wrap the expression in the outer query SELECT list, in an `IFNULL(cnt,0)` to replace a NULL with a zero. Also, it's likely the inline view (derived table) will reduce performance; the inline view isn't necessary.

Comment: the query sample above from serakfalcon is working and return 0 when prodID doesn't appear in tableB, haven't tried the one from Ian.